# App Game Kit BASIC language array out of bound, array empty

Tags: arrays, basic

I am currently using App Game Kit and trying to learn the BASIC language at the same time. I have this error that have happened in this Function, its in this line:
The error show:

```
Array index out of bounds, Index: 0, Array Length: <Empty> in GameRenderer.agc at line 14
```

`holeSprites[I] = holeSprite`

And this is the file that contains the line:

```js
global DIM holeSprites[5]

Function RenderHole()
 holeImage = LoadImage ( "Orb.png" )

 FOR X = 1 to 2
  FOR Y = 1 to 2 
   I = 0
   holeSprite = CreateSprite ( holeImage )
   SetSpriteSize(holeSprite, 70, 100)
   SetSpritePosition ( holeSprite, 100 * X, 170 * Y)
   holeSprites[I] = holeSprite
   inc I
  NEXT Y
 NEXT X 
EndFunction
```

---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
I need help in learning BASIC programming language thanks!

Comment: BASIC or Visual Basic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some basic the lowest array index is 1.
Then you should put the I variable outside the second for..next otherwise you reset the value on each iteration.
The size of holeSprites can be 4, you are assigning before inc and the two "for..next" are iterating 4 times.

Try:

```
global DIM holeSprites[4]

Function RenderHole()
    holeImage = LoadImage ( "Orb.png" )
    I = 1
    FOR X = 1 to 2
        FOR Y = 1 to 2  
            holeSprite = CreateSprite ( holeImage )
            SetSpriteSize(holeSprite, 70, 100)
            SetSpritePosition ( holeSprite, 100 * X, 170 * Y)
            holeSprites[I] = holeSprite
            inc I
        NEXT Y
    NEXT X  
EndFunction
```